# easy steps to make front end form without plugin

Tags: plugins, login, forms, user-registration

i don't know this topic might covered else where. but i am trying to find step by step simply tutorial. to make a plugin where i can add a new page to site. and in that page i put some form. and only registered user can access that.

i managed to make plugin at admin side. but not able to find the tutorial to make a form at front end of website. for registered user only.

please give me some link for it.

my core issues are

1. how can i display custom coded php form in only one page in front end.
2. how can i make that page ristricted for registered user only.
3. how can i customize the login/registration form to add custom fields without using any plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you Bainternet, it was really great answer straight for the question to the solution. with appropriate example links. it helped me a lot to make confirm, that the solution i am thinking is right.

Answer (score 2):

> how can i display custom coded php form in only one page in front end?

The best way to go would be to create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) then create a page inside WordPress admin and select your newly created template for that page.

> how can i make that page ristricted for registered user only?

Normally I would go with my plugin [User Specific Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/) but since you are looking for a solution without a plugin then you can use the [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function in your custom template page to check if the user is logged in or not.

> how can i customize the login/registration form to add custom fields without using any plugin?

take a look at this [nice tutorial](http://tipsforwordpress.com/wordpress/add-custom-field-to-register-form/)

Answer (score 2):

For a custom form without plugin. you can make use of existing hooks in wordpress like template_redirect.This hook get called before re-directing to the new page. you can refer to an in-depth article [here](https://geekswordpress.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-create-custom-submit-form-in.html)

html form

```
<div class="employee">
<input type="hidden" name="show_msg">

<form name="customer_details" method="POST" required="required" class="input-hidden">
Your Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="customer_name">
Your Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="customer_email">
Company: <input type="text" id="company" name="company">
Sex: <input type="radio" name="customer_sex" value="male">Male <input type="radio" name="customer_sex" value="female">Female
<textarea id="post" name="experience" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:400px;width:100%"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<!--?php wp_nonce_field( 'wpshout-frontend-post','form-submit' ); ?-->
</form></div>
```

**PHP Function**

```
function wpshout_frontend_post() {
    wpshout_save_post_if_submitted();
}
add_action('template_redirect','wpshout_frontend_post', 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a shortcode for your form is also an option: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Not really addresses the question in hand